# CSS rotate creates shake of arrow

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am animating an arrow moving from left to right then turn 180deg and move from right to left. For some reasons, when turning arrow with **CSS rotate**, arrow's position gets moved a bit upwards. How can I keep it position the same when moving arrow? The arrow is a image element.

And also how can I get smooth rotate of arrow with CSS3 keyframes?

```css
.bg {
  width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.arrow {
  width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
  animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.arrow img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 10px, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 10px, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 10px, 0);
  }
  53% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="arrow">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Arrow_right.svg/2000px-Arrow_right.svg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif rotate creates arrow shake that's why I set opacity: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.bg {
  width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.arrow {
  width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation:moveRightToLeft 2s 3s infinite linear;
}

.arrow img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(70px, 0);
  }
  50.1% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(-70px, -100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(0, -100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="arrow">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Arrow_right.svg/2000px-Arrow_right.svg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can I know why there is no jump in your animation when arrow get rotated?

Comment: @forethought as you can see there is a sligh difference between to state (50% and 50.1%) so the transition is fast and then no jump

Comment: For first two iteration arrow is showing in different place for a millisecond and disappear when arrow making a turn. Do you know why?

Comment: @forethought didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Please check the link for videocast of animation. http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1501728

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @forethought yes it's a small glitch not always visible .. try to use 50.01% instead of 50.1% .... try to make it close te 50% and see if it disappear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168326/discussion-between-forethought-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the animation to the image inside the arrow.The width and the height of the div creates the problem.Also change   `transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);` to   `transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 0px, 0);`

```css
.bg{
width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.arrow img{
  width: 24px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
                        animation-delay: 2s;
                        -webkit-animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
                        animation-name: moveRightToLeft;
                        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
                        animation-duration: 3s;
                        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
                        animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.arrow img{
max-width: 100%;
}

@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    51% {
        opacity: 0;
         -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(70px, 0px, 0);
    }
    53% {
        opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px,0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px,0px, 0);

    }
    54% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 10px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(-70px, 0px, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0,0px, 0);
        transform: rotateZ(-180deg) translate3d(0, 0,0px);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="arrow">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Arrow_right.svg/2000px-Arrow_right.svg.png">
</div>
```